# Random matrix with independent rows and different distributions

Tags: probability-theory, random-matrices

Given a $M\times P$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ with *independent rows* and the $m$-th row has the form:

$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} f_1(x_{m,1},\dots,x_{m,R}) & f_2(x_{m,1},\dots,x_{m,R}) & \cdots f_P(x_{m,1},\dots,x_{m,R}) \end{bmatrix} .
$$

$x_{m,r}$ are Gaussian i.i.d. random variables and $f_p$ are known (differentiable, smooth) functions. So each row is independent of each other and the columns are dependent and each column has a different distribution.

Is there anything I could say about spectral properties (eigenvalues, singular values, determinant, trace etc. of $\mathbf{X}$ or $(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1}$ or  $(\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})$?

Is there any similar known problem in random matrix theory that can help me with this problem?

Additional information:

> The concrete case I am interested in is where $f_p$ is given as:
>  $$f_p(x_{m,1},\dots,x_{m,R}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} \sum_{r=1}^R x_{m,r}^p $$
>  This means: 1) For $R=1$ the matrix is nothing but a Vandermonde matrix with random nodes 2) For $R>1$, each row is the normalized sum over $R$ rows of a random Vandermonde matrix 3) Each column contains sums of Gaussian random variables, raised to the power of $p$.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think I have specified fairly precicely a pretty non-obvious problem

Comment: Someone’s been downvoting a lot of questions lately that look totally reasonable to me. I don’t know what’s going on but I wouldn’t take it too personally. It’s a fine question! Have you done any numerical experiments?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did very extensive numerical experiments and I have clear numerical outcomes and observations: All mentioned spectral properties improve with increasing $R$ (for the definition of $f_p$ in the spoiler). Did not want to elaborate too much to keep the question targeted and compact. I also have an intuitive explanation. But I am lacking any quantitative insight whatsoever. It would be great if I could get at least some bounds on eigenvalues, determinant, condition number etc.